# FullCalendar (React) - getting dates of current week/month

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am playing out with FullCalendar for React and I can't find in documentation how can I get the start and end date of the current displayed week/month.

Does anyone have example on this one?

Comment: In what situation are you wanting this information? It is available at certain places in the API, so please describe what you want to do with the information and when (e.g. is it in response to some particular event on the page, perhaps?)

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getDate

Comment: I want to be able to paginate reservations. In this case I need that information to send start and end date of view otself to the backend.

Comment: @wobsoriano that is for current date. I am looking for start and end date of current calendalar view. Those are two dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

datesRender will invoke each time the dates displayed are changed

```
<FullCalendar

    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}

    datesRender={(arg) => {
      console.log(arg)
      //arg includes data about current visible dates
      console.log(arg.view.activeStart) //starting visible date
      console.log(arg.view.activeEnd) //ending visible date
    }}

  />
```

Comment: not valid after v5 updates

Answer (score 6):

There is no longer datesRender in FullCalendar version v5. Can use [datesSet](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet) instead which will invoke after the calendar’s date range has been initially set or changed.

```
<FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}

    datesSet={(dateInfo) => {
        console.log(dateInfo.start) //start of the range the calendar date
        console.log(dateInfo.end) //end of the range the calendar date
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

tried @sammyShenker's answer but it didn't work.
Rather found a solution.

```
<FullCalendar

datesSet={(args) => console.log("###datesSet:", args)}
/>
```

Output:

```
{
    "start": "2021-02-27T18:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "startStr": "2021-02-28T00:00:00+05:30",
    "endStr": "2021-04-11T00:00:00+05:30",
    "timeZone": "local",
    "view": {
        "type": "dayGridMonth",
        "dateEnv": {
            "timeZone": "local",
            "canComputeOffset": true,
            "calendarSystem": {},
            "locale": {
                "codeArg": "en",
                "codes": [
                    "en"
                ],
                "week": {
                    "dow": 0,
                    "doy": 4
                },
                "simpleNumberFormat": {},
                "options": {
                    "direction": "ltr",
                    "buttonText": {
                        "prev": "prev",
                        "next": "next",
                        "prevYear": "prev year",
                        "nextYear": "next year",
                        "year": "year",
                        "today": "today",
                        "month": "month",
                        "week": "week",
                        "day": "day",
                        "list": "list"
                    },
                    "weekText": "W",
                    "allDayText": "all-day",
                    "moreLinkText": "more",
                    "noEventsText": "No events to display"
                }
            },
            "weekDow": 0,
            "weekDoy": 4,
            "weekText": "W",
            "cmdFormatter": null,
            "defaultSeparator": " - "
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the start/startStr/end/endStr as per your needs.